# Microsoft Teams: get timezone of user?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm developing a bot for MS Teams and I'm looking to know the timezone of a user, to deliver messages at an appropriate time (e.g. not in the middle of the night).

I didn't found something appropriate in the bot framework REST API. Although messages we receive include a 'clientInfo.country' property, which is a start, but definitely not enough to time messages as we would like.

Comment: I've posted this as feedback (please vote it up) to the Microsoft community here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/5318d0a0-ab7e-ec11-a81b-6045bd7bf64c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is: there’s a `localTimestamp` property that can be used to get the time offset, which is good enough for what I need.

Comment: Isn't the localTimestamp the time of the machine the bot is running on?
If the user is in +0400 and the bot server is in -0800, won't localTimestamp's timezone be -0800 which is not the users timezone?

Comment: I'm reading user messages, I don't need the timestamp for my own bot. I needed to know the timezone of the user who posted the message I'm reading.

Comment: I understand that it is the users timestamp we are looking for. When I test myself I run my bot on localhost of machine 1 using UTC+2, I then change the timezone of machine 2 to -7 and message my bot. The bot responds with the rawLocalTimestamp and localTimestamp. The rawLocalTimestamp appears to show the correct value however the localTimestamp shows it in UTC+2. On top of this if my timezone changes while teams is open I do not receive the updated timezone but the original (-7). Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

On every message to a user, there is an `entities[]` collection, one of which is details of the user's locale. For example (copied/pasted from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#full-inbound-schema-example)):

```
"entities": [
  { 
    "locale": "en-US",
    "country": "US",
    "platform": "Windows",
    "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "type": "clientInfo"
  }
],
```

Comment: I do receive locale/country/platform/type, but I do NOT receive timezone...

Comment: Can you describe more? How you are receiving the message (or equivalently what you are doing on the client to send it) and from what client?

Comment: It's an app published on the Office store. I am receiving the messages from the webhook. I'm not sending messages myself, I'm receiving them from people who installed the bot.

Here's one example of data I receive (without timezone): `"entities":[{"locale":"nb-NO","country":"NO","platform":"iOS","type":"clientInfo"}]`
Here's another one: `"entities":[{"locale":"de-DE","country":"DE","platform":"Windows","type":"
clientInfo"}]`

I checked a few of them, and none include the timezone property.

Comment: Meta: Stack Overflow doesn't use three backticks for code blocks. Use at least four spaces in front of the code (and a newline before the block) instead.

Comment: We are looking into this issue. For now, you can also use offset of localTimestamp and timestamp values.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT have you finished looking into it?

Comment: Could you please explain your scenario bit more? Isn't [timestamp offset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53394030/576503) of any use for you?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT The offset will give you a possible current timezone, but there are many to choose from in the same country and this can lead to daylight savings issues if you need to know the date in the future. For instance Arizona and Utah, where Utah does Daylight Savings while Arizona doesn't. That is why I need to know the exact timezone.

Answer (score 1):

From [@Savageman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211204/savageman) 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53394030/11889556)

> And the answer is: there’s a localTimestamp property that can be used to get the time offset, which is good enough for what I need.

We can solve the issue `"NOT Receive the timezone"` by mapping the `utcOffset` of `localTimestamp` and `country` in `entities` to `timezone`.

I wrote a javascript code to get timezone such as `"Asia/shanghai"` by using the `"localTimestamp": "2019-08-06T18:23:44.259+08:00"` and `"country": "CN"` from `Session` in Teams message.

More details in my github [readme.md](https://github.com/muhualing/microsoft-teams-bot/tree/master/src/utils#about-gettimezonefromsessionjs).

```js
let moment = require("moment-timezone");
let ct = require("countries-and-timezones");

let partOfSampleSession = {
    "message": {
        "entities": [
            {
                "country": "CN",
                "locale": "zh-CN",
                "platform": "Web",
                "type": "clientInfo"
            }
        ],
        "localTimestamp": "2019-08-06T18:23:44.259+08:00"
    }
}

function getTimezoneFromSession(session) {
    // Get the name of country, such as "CN", "JP", "US"
    let country = session.message.entities[0].country;

    // Get the localTimestamp from message in session, such as "2019-08-06T18:23:44.259+08:00"
    let localTimestamp = session.message.localTimestamp;

    // Caculate the utfOffset of "localTimestamp", such as "480" by "2019-08-06T18:23:44.259+08:00"
    let utcOffsetOfLocalTime = moment().utcOffset(localTimestamp).utcOffset();

    // Mapping country to an object array which contains utcOffsets and it's corresponding timezones
    // One element from mxTimezones is {"utcOffset": "480", "name": "Asia/Shanghai"}
    let mxTimezones = ct.getTimezonesForCountry(country);

    // get the same timezone as localtime utcOffset from timezones in a country
    let timezone = "";
    mxTimezones.forEach(mxTimezone => {
        if (mxTimezone.utcOffset == utcOffsetOfLocalTime) {
            timezone = mxTimezone.name;
        }
    });
    return timezone;
}
let timezone = getTimezoneFromSession(partOfSampleSession);
// timezone = "Asia/Shanghai"
console.log(timezone);


// example of ct.getTimezonesForCountry("US")
// mxTimezones = [
//      {
//          "name": "America/New_York",
//          "utcOffset": "-300",
//      },
//      {
//          "name": "America/Los_Angeles",
//          "utcOffset": "-480",
//      }
//      ...
//      27 elements
//      ...
// ]
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you can't get the time zone until the user sends something to the bot. Unfortunately, it appears as though there's no better answer. I've been looking for an alternative, perhaps hooking into a conversation init event or something similar, but the payloads I've seen are all missing the user's time zone.