# not getting time zone in activity object returned from MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Not getting time zone in activity object returned from MS Teams...

I am able to get the activity object from the user message posted on `MS Teams` but time zone is coming as `null`.I need to identify the time zone of the user.

Below is the activity object.

```
Activity Object: {
"type": "message",
"id": "1566815985480",
"timestamp": "2019-08-26T10:39:45.5003126+00:00",
"localTimestamp": "2019-08-26T16:09:45.5003126+05:30",
"localTimezone": null,
"serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/",
"channelId": "msteams",
"from": {
    "id": "29:14rYXH-yjWkIa0Z6jjjGWFmebOM-n4Jfoo2OfOY-ofYqAu4cvDv9CF9BV-D2oHTwjQu1LWNkv6Q7d2IlR5N2oQQ",
    "name": "Anubhooti Bhatnagar (c)",
    "aadObjectId": "7b9dfbc1-0add-49ac-9327-2f62b102b5d6",
    "role": null
},
"conversation": {
    "isGroup": null,
    "conversationType": "personal",
    "id": "a:12S0SAjSmD3ugQCV-ZgdRLeN6gbxJM5Xa7dfomtQWes9FOCGTyIrgPLHSjAs-08wDElyxhP5TgMant9tDqx5-G0HXE9W2gPW2vfo0aK9UDi5wS5pbhzd_wO17MIfWZTke",
    "name": null,
    "aadObjectId": null,
    "role": null,
    "tenantId": "b39138ca-3cee-4b4a-a4d6-cd83d9dd62f0"
},
"recipient": {
    "id": "28:34d3d716-049a-4363-9ade-a2fdf6fe8f5b",
    "name": "GenieChatBotDev",
    "aadObjectId": null,
    "role": null
},
"textFormat": "plain",
"attachmentLayout": null,
"membersAdded": null,
"membersRemoved": null,
"reactionsAdded": null,
"reactionsRemoved": null,
"topicName": null,
"historyDisclosed": null,
"locale": "en-US",
"text": "hi",
"speak": null,
"inputHint": null,
"summary": null,
"suggestedActions": null,
"attachments": null,
"entities": [{
    "type": "clientInfo",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "country": "US",
    "platform": "Windows"
}],
"channelData": {
    "tenant": {
        "id": "b39138ca-3cee-4b4a-a4d6-cd83d9dd62f0"
    }
},
"action": null,
"replyToId": null,
"label": null,
"valueType": null,
"value": null,
"name": null,
"relatesTo": null,
"code": null,
"expiration": null,
"importance": null,
"deliveryMode": null,
"listenFor": null,
"textHighlights": null,
"semanticAction": null,
"callerId": null
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. It is a known bug we are working on it.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT what is the status of the bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue which we are working on. Meanwhile, if you are looking for time difference, that you could get using localTimestamp and timestamp values.

Comment: what is the status of the bug?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT For my use case the timestamp is not enough. 

Is there any update on this subject?

I also saw your comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282405/microsoft-teams-get-timezone-of-user about the same issue.